# How do I save images in database in strapi instead of the default file system

Tags: node.js, postgresql, strapi

How to save the uploaded image in the database instead of file system in strapi api. Is is possible to override the strapi default media storage as file system approach.

Comment: Putting lots of images in database will make your backups huge and impractical.

Comment: Answering the second part of the question :Its possible to override a default provider. Refer [this](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#using-a-provider) . Here's the list of [providers](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=strapi-provider-upload-&ranking=popularity&page=0&perPage=20) .

Comment: @bobflux thank you very much for the suggestion, will note this in the future development. Most of the files will be saved in the file system but however is there a way to save few(max 10)  files directly  in the db? and not on cloud. or I will have to write a code?